# What is "&" doing in CSS

Tags: css

Just saw following in a CSS file, what is that & mean?

```
& > p {
            margin-left: -15px;
            margin-right: -15px;
}
```

Comment: it is most likely from a less or sass file, do you have more context?

Comment: That probably wasn't a CSS file.  In LESS and SASS that means the parent selector

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26522363/1623249

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-29/less-css-secrets-of-the-ampersand/

Comment: Ah, I see, it is a less selector